# How to write data into text file in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, file-io, java-me

I want to know how to write text content to a file. I have a BasicEditField and a save button. When the button is clicked, then the BasicEditField text content should be saved into a text file, so I can retrieve that file later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the specifics on [FileConnection](http://www.microemu.org/microemu-extensions/microemu-jsr-75/apidocs/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html). Hope that helps! itsteju beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `FileConnection` interface for `javax.microedition.io.file`

Answer (score 0):

```
/** File connection object */
            FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open(Const.FILE_PATH);
            if (fc.exists() == false) {
                fc.create();// create file at the location path
            }

            OutputStream os = fc.openOutputStream();

            os.write(log.getBytes()); // Write text to file

            os.close();
            fc.close();// close the file connection object
```